# Tidal cycles : parse error on input `let'

Tags: syntax-error, tidalcycles

I do tests to learn tidal, I'm a video via youtube and the problem is that "let" is not recognized and I do not understand why !? :s

thank a lot

```
setcps 0.6

d0
  let timeBetweenStutters = shift' 10 $ choose [0.0625, (0.0625/2), 0.125]
  let stutterEffect = ( (|* lpf 0.7) . (|* gain 0.9) )
  let initialTime = shift' 11 $ choose [(0.125*3), 0.125, 0.0625*3]
  d1
    $ stutWith 2 initialTime ( stutWith 20 timeBetweenStutters stutterEffect )
    $ s "other:3"
    # gain 1.2
    # size 0.9
    # lpf 10000

d2 $ s "other:5" # gain 1.2

  hush
```

Comment: first thing first, it should be `do` and not `d0`. However, couple of things: 1) I do not see a real case for its use as you happen to use the variables defined inside the block only once; 2) when solving for that error I then have errors for the lines where `shift'` is applied.